# Formatting and parsing Joda-Time based date and time objects in JSP

Tags: hibernate, jsp, jstl, jodatime

I'm using [joda-time-jsptags-1.1.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/files/joda-time-jsptags/1.1.1/) to format and parse [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) based date and time objects on JSP pages with the following taglib.

```
<%@taglib prefix="joda" uri="http://www.joda.org/joda/time/tags" %>
```

I have dates in Oracle database which are stored using the standard UTC format.

Using the following JSTL tags,

```
<c:set var="startDate" value="${row.discountStartDate}"/>
<c:set var="endDate" value="${row.discountEndDate}"/>
```

these two dates are displayed in the following format respectively.

```
2013-02-16T22:31:59.000+05:30 
2013-02-28T22:32:03.000+05:30
```

I need to display these dates in a specific format using a specific time zone. I'm trying to parse these dates as follows.

```
<joda:parseDateTime var="startDate"
                    pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
                    value="${row.discountStartDate}"
                    dateTimeZone="Asia/Kolkata"/>

<joda:parseDateTime var="endDate"
                    pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
                    value="${row.discountStartDate}"
                    dateTimeZone="Asia/Kolkata"/>
```

I expect these dates to be parsed in the given format and zone. I'm however, getting the following exception.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format:
>   "2013-02-16T22:31:59.000+05:30" is malformed at
>   "13-02-16T22:31:59.000+05:30"

How to parse these dates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dates returned via Hibernate by `row.discountStartDate` and `row.discountEndDate` in this example are obviously the type of [`org.joda.time.DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html).

These properties are designated by [`org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime`](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/jadira/usertype/dateandtime/joda/PersistentDateTime.html) in the respective entity class like,

```
@Column(name = "DISCOUNT_START_DATE")
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime discountStartDate;

@Column(name = "DISCOUNT_END_DATE")    
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime discountEndDate;
```

Therefore, there is no need to parse these date once again. I just need to format these dates with a given format and time zone, just like the following.

```
<joda:format var="startDate"
             value="${row.discountStartDate}"
             pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
             style="F-"
             dateTimeZone="Asia/Kolkata"/>

<joda:format var="endDate"
             value="${row.discountEndDate}"
             pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
             style="F-"
             dateTimeZone="Asia/Kolkata"/>
```

The value attribute of the format tag must be of type [`ReadableInstant`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/ReadableInstant.html) or [`ReadablePartial`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/ReadablePartial.html)

The `style` attribute is the style to use for parsing. It specifies two characters, one for date, one for time.

```
S = Short
M = Medium
L = Long
F = Full
- = None
```

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/jsptags/userguide.html